# What is the purpose of settings.gradle.kts?

Tags: gradle

What is the purpose of `settings.gradle.kts`? Why can't those propperties be initialized in `build.gradle.kts`? Why do we need a separate file for this?

Comment: The build file contains build logic while the settings.gradle.kts contains overall project information like other sub projects that are part of it. Another function it serves is to give a boundary to gradle as gradle is looking for a settings.gradle.kts in it's current and all parent directories until it finds on. Like you can run a gradle task of a sub project when you are in it and gradle will know it's a sub project because the parent contains the settings file and tells it that htis one is part of a multi project setup. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

[Gradle works in phases](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html)

1. Initialization
2. Configuration
3. Execution

`settings.gradle.kts` is used in the initialization phase. There's only one [Settings object](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html) per Gradle build, and `settings.gradle.kts` is used to configure it.

Each Gradle build has at least one [Project object](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html), depending on how many subprojects there are. These are configured via `build.gradle.kts` files in the configuration phase.

#### Settings initialization

The Settings object must be configured first, and separately, because Gradle determines and configures a lot of properties and behaviours in the initialization phase, which cannot be determined on-the-fly in the configuration phase.

For example...

###### Multi-project builds

Gradle supports [multi-project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#multi_project_builds). [Subprojects are declared](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:adding_subprojects) in `settings.gradle.kts`, and that's [how Gradle discovers](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/fine_tuning_project_layout.html#sub:project_locations) other `build.gradle.kts` configurations.

> *Aside*: Gradle can't automatically scan for nested `build.gradle.kts` files because
>
> - they might not be part of the current project, for example
>
>   - if there's some integration test code that has a test `build.gradle.kts`.
>   - if there's a nested project that's an [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html), and so not part of the current build.
> - a subproject might not have a `build.gradle.kts` file, which can happen if a subproject is configured via `subprojects {}` or `allprojects{}` (even though both are [discouraged](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins_vs_cross_configuration))

###### Gradle Build Cache

The Gradle Build cache is [configured during the initialization phase](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:build_cache_configure), for an entire Gradle build.

###### Build plugins

Gradle plugins are usually used to configure a Gradle Project, but plugins can be used to configure *anything*, including the Gradle build.

One example of a build plugin is the [Gradle Build Scan](https://docs.gradle.com/enterprise/gradle-plugin/) plugin, which measures the performance of Gradle builds. It wouldn't be possible to measure the performance correctly if the Gradle build had already started, so it must be applied before the Configuration phase.

#### But `settings.gradle.kts` isn't strictly required...

If a Gradle project *isn't* a multi-project build, then a `settings.gradle.kts` isn't strictly required. Gradle will still work, with sensible defaults, although [one is recommended for improved performance, consistency, and clarity](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#always_define_a_settings_file).

Comment: Can I access variable declared in settings from build and sub-project builds?